# How to create unique database name from sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create separate database for different users.The database name would be that user's name.
I tried the following

```
$user=preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#','',$_GET['u']); 

if(! $connect_dude )
 {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
 }
else{
  echo 'Connected successfully<br />';
 }

$sql2 = "CREATE DATABASE '.$user.'";
$query2=mysqli_query($connect_dude,$sql2);
if($query2===TRUE){
 echo "Database created";
}
else{
 echo "Not created";
}
```

but it doesn't work.

If I use static name for database,that works.That create database.
But I need different database name for different user.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really need to create an entire new database for each user? Normally you'd just have a users table and reference it with foreign keys.

Comment: Why are you creating a different database per user

Comment: Remove the quotes and dots `'.$user.'` and use backticks `\`` around that variable.

Comment: @Fred-ii-You are the savior.You are the best.You helped mw with my last ques. too.It worked.Please put that on answer sec.And,I would choose this as answer

Comment: @Quentin Yes I do.Because I need lots of table on that user's database

Comment: @SalimKhan — You can have lots of tables using the user table for a foreign key.

Comment: @Fred-ii-Hi,your suggestion worked.Can you pls put that on answer sec

Comment: @SalimKhan It has been done as per your request.

Comment: @Quentin can you please provide me a link,where I can learn about foreign key?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: @Quentin thanks a lot for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"@Fred-ii-You are the savior.You are the best.You helped mw with my last ques. too.It worked.Please put that on answer sec.And,I would choose this as answer"*

As per OP's request:

Remove the quotes and dots `'.$user.'` and use backticks around the variable.

```
$sql2 = "CREATE DATABASE `$user`";
```

[**Tables and column identifiers**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html) require either no quotes or backticks.

Although it is best using backticks, should the variable contain a [**reserved keyword**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), a space, a hyphen or any other character(s) that SQL may not agree with.

---

Add `or die(mysqli_error($connect_dude))` to `mysqli_query()`

which would have signaled the error.

Answer (score 2):

If `$user` is `foo`, then you're trying to create a database named `.foo.`

Try any of these instead:

```
$sql2 = "CREATE DATABASE '$user'";
$sql2 = "CREATE DATABASE '{$user}'";
$sql2 = "CREATE DATABASE '" . $user . "'";
```

And note that even though you're filtering $_GET['u'] to be alpha-numeric only, you can STILL cause SQL syntax errors, e.g. consider someone passing in `u=table` or `01234`. Neither of those are valid DB (or table, or field) names.

Comment: And use backticks instead of single quotation marks

Comment: none of them worked.but using `$user` it worked,as suggested by Fred-ii.Thanks though